# Run craft up command in deployment pipeline without prompts

Tags: craft4, deployment, cli

I am deploying a Craft website with Bitbucket Pipelines.
Basically what it does is spinning up a container that runs composer install and builds my CSS and JS with webpack. The vendor folder and js/css builds are kept as artefacts to be deployed to the server.
So far so good.

However when I am doing some updates locally (updating craft version or plugins) and push these to my repository, deploy them and run `php craft up` I get the following message:

````
Total 4 new Craft migrations to be applied:
    - m230531_123004_add_entry_type_show_status_field
    - m230607_102049_add_entrytype_slug_translation_columns
    - m230710_162700_element_activity
    - m230820_162023_fix_cache_id_type```
````

This is actually prompting me to answer yes or no.
But since this is a automatic pipeline there won't be any input from me.

Is there an option I can add to the `php craft up` command which will always choose yes so that the pipeline will complete successfully?

For example with `composer install` I added the `--no-interaction` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run most of Craft's console commands using the `--interactive=0` flag which will disable interactive prompts for the command. More details in the docs here: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html#global-options

Comment: To add to Steve's answer, here's a good set of commands to run in the pipeline: `php craft up --interactive=0`, `clear-caches/compiled-templates --interactive=0`, `clear-caches/cp-resources --interactive=0`, `clear-caches/data --interactive=0`

Comment: Awesome!
@MaxStrebel Nice addition